# How can I store integers wider than 32 bits in a Gtk.ListStore?

Tags: python, gtk, gobject

It seems that `DirEntry`'s `f.stat().st_size` can return values larger than 2147483647 for the file size, which - in my case - is correct. But when I try to store it in a `Gtk.ListStore` which has the corresponding column set to `int`, I get an `OverflowError`:

> OverflowError: 2200517068 not in range -2147483648 to 2147483647

How do I solve this? Is `int` in `ListStore` limited to 4 bytes?

BTW, I'm using Python 3.9.5 and GUdev 237.

```
        self.file_store = Gtk.ListStore(str,    # File name
                                        int,    # File size
                                        str)    # Mod time, as YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss
        ...
        self.file_store.append(
                        (f.name,
                         f.stat().st_size,
                         ftime))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GObject.TYPE_INT64` to allow signed 64-bit integers in the list store:

```python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk

list_store = Gtk.ListStore(GObject.TYPE_INT64)
list_store.append((1 << 48,))   # look ma! no error!
```

You will probably want signed 64-bit integers given that [`off_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Position-Primitive.html#index-off_005ft) (what `st_size` is defined as) is defined to be a signed type, and on most platforms it is at most 64 bits wide; 8 pebibytes ought to be enough for everyone.

You can refer to other primitive GObject types in similar way, using `TYPE_name` constants in the `GObject` namespace.

Comment: Thanks and appreciated! I had solved the issue by saving the filesize as a string. Though not as efficient as UINT64, I needed the size as string later anyway. (BTW, 'ought to be enough for everyone'. That's what they said about 640kB PC memory not too long ago)

Comment: Yes. That was the joke.